# parse only required data using nutch

Tags: python-3.x, nutch

I have build nutch crawler to crawl news websites but the problem is I am getting all data from a particular website which I dont want, My question is how can I configure nutch to parse only the data that I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not a really good question let's try to put some context. First, you need to define what is *the data that you want*, this usually means:

- crawl specific URLs.
- extract specific data in the HTML of the pages (something like a specific paragraph, heading, etc.)

For the specific URLs case, you have the `URLFilters` that should allow you to exclude whatever URLs that you want. In this case, since you only mention 1 website this should work.

For the second case, you can take a look at these 3 alternatives:

- https://github.com/BayanGroup/nutch-custom-search
- http://www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1870